# Calling Javascript prototype method from another method

Tags: javascript

I am not a javascript object oriented pro and am stuck for a while now. I am trying to implement a call back api so that i can detect when an element is being scrolled. Unfortunately, am unable to fire the prototype method from another method. Please help

```
     //HTML
     //<div style="width:500px;height:500px;"id="myElement"></div>

     //JS
       mousewheelListen=function(){
            this.el.addEventListener('wheel',);//How do i call Scroller.prototype.scrolling() ?
        }
        Scroller=function(el){//Constructor
            this.el=el;
            mousewheelListen.call(this);
        }
        Scroller.prototype.scrolling=function(callback){//
            callback.call(this);
        }
        
        
        var el=document.getElementById('myElement');
        var myScroller=new Scroller(el);
        myScroller.scrolling(function(){//Listening when scrolling
            console.log('scrolling');
        });
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `this.el.addEventListener('wheel', event => this.scrolling(event))`

Comment: @Scotty. Still gives a message that "callback.call is not a function".

Comment: Well, I did pass into `this.scrolling()` an event object, not a callback function. If you want to pass in some sort of callback, you'll need to do that instead. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish with this callback parameter.

Comment: If, all you're trying to do is to get some function to run when that event fires, and nothing more, then perhaps you want to simply remove the `callback.call(this);` line, and replace it with `console.log('scrolling');`.

Comment: This is great. Is there a way i can call myScroller.scrolling(function(){  })?

Comment: Are you asking how to call the function you're currently passing into `myScroller.scrolling()`? This is where, I think, there's some logical issues in this code. What's this scrolling function supposed to do? Are you supposed to call it with a callback, with the expectation that the provided callback will be called every time this event fires? Or is this scrolling function itself supposed to be called everytime the event fires? Right now it seems your scrolling function is trying to do both of these things?

Comment: Sure, you are right. Am new to Javascript OOP but i figure out now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick.

Moved all DOM element dependent code into a function that runs after all DOM Content has been loaded.
Added the `wheel` event listener on the referenced element

```js
var myScroller;

function Scroller(el) { //Constructor
    this.el=el;
    this.el.addEventListener('wheel', this.scrolling, { passive: true })
}

Scroller.prototype.scrolling = function(event){ //
    console.log(event);
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let el = document.getElementById('myElement');
  myScroller=new Scroller(el);
})
```

```html
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black" id="myElement"></div>
```

Below is a demonstration of the same thing using three different techniques, all of which end up with a different version of `this` in the actual scroll function.  They all work (pretty much the same) and there's arguments that could be made for and against any of them, and people may have strong opinions about all of them.  For me, it comes down to "what is going to be the most useful at the time?"

```js
var myScroller;

function Scroller(el) { //Constructor
    this.el=el;
    this.el.addEventListener('wheel', this.scrolling, { passive: true })
    document.getElementById('element2').addEventListener('wheel', this.scrolling2.bind(this), { passive: true })
}

Scroller.prototype.scrolling = function(event){ //
    console.log(`this is myElement: ${this == document.getElementById('myElement')}`)
}

Scroller.prototype.scrolling2 = function(event){ //
    console.log(`this is myScroller: ${this == myScroller}`)
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById('element3').addEventListener('wheel', (event) => { console.log(`this is window: ${this == window}`) }, { passive: true })
  let el = document.getElementById('myElement');
  myScroller=new Scroller(el);
})
```

```html
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black" id="myElement"></div>
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black" id="element2"></div>
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black" id="element3"></div>
```

I would call the below the "cleanest" version because it's binding instantiations of anonymous DOM Manipulation methods to DOM objects.

```js
let attachScroller = (element) => element.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) { console.log(this.id) }.bind(element), { passive: true })

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  attachScroller(document.getElementById('myElement'))
  attachScroller(document.getElementById('element2'))
})
```

```html
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black" id="myElement"></div>
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black" id="element2"></div>
```

Comment: You'll want to either pass in `this.scrolling.bind(this)` or `event => this.scrolling(this)`, otherwise the `this` value won't be correct in the `Scroller.prototype.scrolling` function.

Comment: @ScottyJamison It's not really clear what `this` should actually be when the scrolling function is called.

Comment: Thanks you guys saved my day. I just needed a way to call back scrolling from another method which you have helped me accomplish.

Comment: Generally, a method of a "class" should be called with a "this" value that corresponds to an instance of that class. Right now, with `this.scrolling`, you're actually plucking the method `scrolling` right off of an existing instance (`this`), and then letting that get called without preserving the fact that it came from that specific instance. If you really want to call the method with an `undefined` this value, I would pluck the method from the prototype instead of from an existing instance, as that looks less like a mistake. e.g. `addEventListener(..., Scroller.prototype.scrolling, ...)`.

Comment: @philoczar Scotty has a really really good point about `bind`.  In Javascript, `this` can be transferred around programmatically - which is a very powerful thing, but it can be hard to get used to.  You will definitely want to bind the `scrolling` function as shown in his comments if you're going to rely on it for anything.   (You don't actually need the Scroller object at all).  (In this version it's being bound to `e1`, which may not be what you want, and isn't really very OO as Scotty explains)

Comment: Sure. I agree @ScottyJamison solution solves the OP

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that here:

```
myScroller.scrolling(function(){//Listening when scrolling
  console.log('scrolling');
});
```

You are invoking a callback. Your addEventListener not invoke your callback, invoke your scrolling function with an WheelEvent, not a function. The only point in which is invoked witha functión is in the previous piece of code.

You can simply do this:

```
mousewheelListen=function(){
  this.el.addEventListener('wheel', event => Scroller.prototype.scrolling.call(this, event));
}

Scroller=function(el){//Constructor
  this.el=el;
  mousewheelListen.call(this);
}
Scroller.prototype.scrolling=function(){//Listening when scrolling
  console.log('scrolling');
}

var el=document.getElementById('myElement');
var myScroller=new Scroller(el);
```

Comment: `this.el.addEventListener('wheel', this.scrolling);` - This doesn't work. It'll cause `this.scrolling` to be called without the correct `this` value. You either have to pass in `this.scrolling.bind(this)` or `event => this.scrolling(event)`

Comment: Tested this does not work

Comment: I think now, using call, is ok.

Comment: Yep, that works too